# Formatting to a page html

Tags: html

The text in my source code is formatted properly, but when it shows up in the browser all the formatting disappears. Is there a tag I could add to the paragraph tag to make the text properly format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use the `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags to preserve formatting instead of the `<p>` tag

Answer (score 2):

The `<pre>` tag sounds like what you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="white-space:pre">
    hereIsSomeSourceCode();
    if (blah == 3)
       doSomething();
</div>
```